# Ito process with white noise

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I would like to solve following system of SDEs,

```
dx_i[t] = f[x_i[t]]*dt + dw_i[t]
```

where `d` denotes `\[DifferentialD]` and `w_i[t]` corresponds to white noise, which means that $\langle w_i(t)\rangle = 0$ and $\langle w_i(t)w_j(t')\rangle = R\delta_{ij}\delta(t-t')$ ($\langle...\rangle$ denotes time averagin). I know that there is `WhiteNoiseProcess` function in Mathematica but when I try

```
w_i ~ WhiteNoiseProcess[1]
```

my code do not work. So, I technically write down

```
ItoProces[dx_i[t]==f[x_i[t]]*dt + dw_i[t], w_i ~ WhiteNoiseProcess[1],...]
```

Naively, I tried `WienerProcess[0,1]` which is obviosly incorrect set-up. So, my questions are:

1. **How to solve numerically SDE with white noise in right hand side?**
2. **Does `ItoProcess` function is the simplest and most appropriate tool for solving SDEs in Wolfram Mathematica?**
3. **If `ItoProcess` is appropriate function for solving coupled system of SDEs, how to implement white noise?**

Comment: Your syntax for `ItoProcess` in incorrect. Check the help of [`ItoProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ItoProcess.html) to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhiteNoiseProcess is a discrete-time process, so I'm not sure what you intend by using its derivative "dw_i" in your SDE.

Do you mean instead the continuous WienerProcess? If so, see the first example in the documentation for ItoProcess to set up and solve a SDE.

ItoProcess can also handle coupled systems.

Comment: You answer clarifies a lot, thanks!

Comment: I misundertestood relation between Wiener process and white noise process. With your answer, I have revised it and now everything clear